# Why my ADF pipeline error with batch size?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to copy data from MongoDB source side but I got an error as below.

`Invalid cast from 'System.Int64' to 'System.Nullable 1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.`

[Error when run pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhOWs.png)

The pipeline run normally if I remove the batchSize. But the batch size gets added automactically after I save the pipeline and the error shows up again when I re-run the pipeline.

========

I investigated in the pipeline and found the problem. I updated the Mongo Atlas linked service using V2 Driver version. When I changed it to V1, every thing work normally.
Thank you all.

Comment: what is your desination

Comment: When I try to use mongo atlas v2 driver and click import schema, I get the same error.

Comment: We experienced same issue.. switching to V1 driver worked for us as well